# Get first letter of the string and full last name

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to figure out how can I refactor my code to get a first letter and last name but if it is only one word to get the word without the first letter. When is only one word getting the first letter as well? E.G If it is name@abc.com then becomes nname@abc.com if it is johndoe@abc.com is getting right jdoe@abc.com is there a way to fix that? I would really appreciate it if someone can help? Here is my Code:

```
     var fullName = item.getValue('abc12312').toLowerCase().split(' ');
     var lastName = fullName[fullName.length - 1];
     var firstLetter = fullName[0].charAt(0);
     if(fullName != '') {
     var email = firstLetter + lastName + '@abc12123.com';
     }
```

Comment: You must set some rules to achieve what you want. E.G. how to determine name and surname in johndoe or other names dynamically

Answer (score 1):

hadn't tested the code, but mostly it will work

```js
// get input value from HTML and convert it as an array ;
const fullName = document.getElementById('fullname').toLowerCase().split(' ');

let firstLetterOrWord;

if(fullName.length === 1){
  // only one word
  firstLetterOrWord = fullName[0]
} else {
  // two words  
  // first character of first elemment of array 
  firstLetterOrWord = fullName[0][0]

}
// if not found -> empty string
const lastName = fullName[1] || '';

const email = firstLetterOrWord + lastName + '@abc12123.com';
```

```html
<input id="fullname" type="text">
```

Comment: You should define `item` somehow, otherwise code snippet is useless.

Comment: i'm assuming he's defining it somewhere in HTML, will update the answer

Comment: I think, if it is just `John`, they'd want `john@abc.com`, not `j@abc.com`

Comment: @adiga, yes that is correct, if it is only john should be john@abc.com that is the main thing that I am trying to achieve. For the questions above item is just a parameter that takes data. Thanks to everyone! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Now it only getting names with two words and ignoring names with one word. I assume the array is not quite right? Any thougts? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand what every function you've mentioned in your code block does. Also, please define/mention what item is in your codeblock because we do not have any knowledge/reference as to what it is.

```
     // get the full name
     var fullName = item.getValue('abc12312').toLowerCase().split(' ');

     // get the last name
     var lastName = fullName[fullName.length - 1];

     // get the first letter
     var firstLetter = fullName[0][0]

     if (lastName != ''){
         const email = firstLetter + lastName + '@abc12123.com';
     }else{
         const email = fullName[0] + '@abc12123.com';
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a function/method that:

1. accepts that string as an input value
2. count the number of characters in that supplied string value
3. if it exceeds 2, than you can use JavaScript [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or array index methods to return the first and last.
4. **OR** return the first char if it's count is lower
   than 2.